# Replace ensembl gene ID with gene symbol in a large GMT file

Tags: r

I know there are similar questions out there but I literally have spent all day on google and cannot find the answer to my issue.
I have a GMT file where I need to replace the ensembl IDs with gene symbols for running a gene set analysis, I have a dataframe that lists the ensembl IDs with their matching gene symbols.
I can run this code for one column and it works:

```
GMTdf$V3 <- Gene_list$hgnc_symbol[match(GMTdf$V3, Gene_list$ensembl_gene_id)]
```

But what I CANNOT figure out how to do is loop it for the 495 columns of the GMT file I have. I tried so many things and nothing works. The only thing that looked promising was the following code but it replaces everything with NAs.

```
GMTdf[,3:495] = Gene_list$hgnc_symbol[GMTdf[,3:495], Gene_list$ensembl_gene_id)]
```

I have tried using dplyr mutate and advice given in StackOverflow on replacing ensembl IDs with gene symbols but I am too much of an amateur coder to figure it out. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` to apply a function for multiple columns.

```
cols <- 3:495
GMTdf[cols] <- lapply(GMTdf[cols] function(x) 
                      Gene_list$hgnc_symbol[match(x, Gene_list$ensembl_gene_id)])
```

In `dplyr`,  you can do the same with `across`.

```
GMTdf <- GMTdf %>% mutate(across(cols, 
                   ~Gene_list$hgnc_symbol[match(., Gene_list$ensembl_gene_id)]))
```